# Are Visual Studio Express and SharpDevelop Project Interchangeable?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharpdevelop

I'm starting to learn WPF and currently use Visual Studio Express 2010 at home. I want to be able to work on my projects at work but I am unable to install any unauthorized software on my computer. I downloaded SharpDevelop 4 and changed it so I can run it from my USB drive. SharpDelvelop will open Visual Studio projects but are there any issues I should be aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use a project in both Visual Studio 2010 and SharpDevelop 4.0 without any problems. SharpDevelop does not convert the project to another format. SharpDevelop has supported msbuild projects that work in Visual Studio since version 2.0 was released which was about four years ago.

The main issue to be aware of is that SharpDevelop 4.0 is still an early beta release so there are going to be bugs and missing features.